# how to retrieve the firebase database values only once without listening to childvalues even though they have changed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, fragmentstatepageradapter

I have this scenario where in my app i am trying to query the child nodes and pass it on the list to recyclerview adapter and here comes the problem when i am scrolling up the recycler view items and if some one has inserted a post, my recyclerview is again coming to first post item and also i am using the viewpager with three fragments and whatever fragment i am on I am rolling back to the first fragment if some one has inserted the post how to solve this.
I have implemented this in following way mentioned below.

one way im thinking is i thought i would not listen to the childevent changes instead i would query the results and populate recyclerview later not listening to child events so that way everything states as it is and i dont know in firebase how do you retrieve values without implementing listeners I tried the singleValueEventListener that way still the behavior is same rolling back to first item or first fragment

guide me through solution how to get rid of this behavior.

```
Query query= databasePostsReference.orderByChild("timestamp");

       query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                List<UserPostPOJO> listposts = new ArrayList<UserPostPOJO>();
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: entered list adding");
                    UserPostPOJO post = 
                    snapshot.getValue(UserPostPOJO.class);
                    listposts.add(0,post);
                }
                if(listposts.isEmpty()){
                    empty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else
                {
                    empty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    makelist(listposts);
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        }); 




private void makelist(List<UserPostPOJO> listposts) {
        list = listposts;
        Log.d(TAG,"size is "+ list.size()+"");

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new 
        LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        CustomRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new 
        CustomRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), list,"recentfragment");
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a method called `removeEventListener()` that you can call to remove a specific `event listener`. You get data out from your database and than call this method. So in order to make this work, please use the following code:

```
databaseReference.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
```

In which `databaseReference` is the reference where you intially put the listener.

For more details please read the [offcial doc](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-detaching).

Hope it helps.

Comment: waw i completely forgot about that ill read and try to implement thanks for this

Comment: Hi Alex I hae tried removing the listeners but still the behaviour is same can you guide me through this.
what I have added ,I have taken out the inline listener made a listener object and add following line within the onDataChange method after makelist method within the onDataChange method
query.removeEventListener(listener);

Comment: The practice is to remove your listener according to the activity life-cycle. Most of the time you need to remove the listener in `onPause()` or `onStop()` methods. But according to your needs you can remove the listener after you queried the database once. The flow is like this: `create the reference -> create the listener -> query -> get the data only once -> remove the listener`.

Comment: I have tried this and now the data doesnot load but the behaviour is still the same it rolls back to first fragment and i tried to debug by putting some log messages and every time some one enters post it is invoking again from mauthstatelistener so i tried to remove mauthstatelistener too but dint workout

Comment: What is the error when you are trying to remove the `mAuthStateListener`?

Comment: there is no error but its the behaviour i have finished building my app and this is only thing bugging me

Comment: I was calling it two times and was it taking it out only once i had to cal only once that fixed my issue. thanks for the help @Alex

Comment: Great Abhilash. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Firebase has a `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` which can be set to a `RecyclerView`. It takes a `DatabaseReference` or `Query` object and handles all the data synchronization between your database and your view.

Answer (score 0):

For a database reference object, the same way one can add an event listener, it can also be removed, using `removeEventListener`.

Instead of creating an anonymous object like this

```
    Query query= databasePostsReference.orderByChild("timestamp");

    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            List<UserPostPOJO> listposts = new ArrayList<UserPostPOJO>();
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: entered list adding");
                UserPostPOJO post = 
                snapshot.getValue(UserPostPOJO.class);
                listposts.add(0,post);
            }
            if(listposts.isEmpty()){
                empty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else
            {
                empty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                makelist(listposts);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

you can create a named object of `ValueEventListener` and remove it from the database reference object using `removeEventListener`, at the end of the `onDataChange` method

```
    Query query= databasePostsReference.orderByChild("timestamp");

    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            List<UserPostPOJO> listposts = new ArrayList<UserPostPOJO>();
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: entered list adding");
                UserPostPOJO post = 
                snapshot.getValue(UserPostPOJO.class);
                listposts.add(0,post);
            }
            if(listposts.isEmpty()){
                empty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else
            {
                empty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                makelist(listposts);
            }

            query.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    }); 

    query.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
```

The code inside `onDataChange` method gets executed only once as the `ValueEventListener` object is removed as soon as the last line of the method gets executed.